# Wordpress register and enqueue various scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm still quite new to wordpress, and having built and developed my first theme (that all works fine). My second attempt at a CMS site on wordpress I am having some trouble with. That trouble being the jQuery.
The site all works (bar the jQuery) which is the frustrating part, after reading up about how to correctly call jQuery in wordpress, I read that the proper way to do it is via enqueue the script in the functions file.
Taking the code from my functions.php from my first site and using it on this one

```
<?php
function fff_script_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/themes/wahoo/js/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fff_script_method');
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work this time round, and I also need to call various scripts, last time round I called this script via functions.php and the rest in my header.php file using the regular method

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wahoo/js/jquery.imagesloaded.js"></script>
```

But again this doesn't seem to be working this time round, and any changes I make in the function.php file just result in a syntax error which then means I have to replace the file on the FTP again.
It's incredibly frustrating and I can't seem to figure out why the jQuery is loading this time round, I have also gone to the effort of making sure my jQuery files aren't conflicting and using 'jQuery' instead of '$'.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and how do you correctly register and enqueue more than one script so I can see if that works too?

Comment: Why are you deregistering jquery?

Comment: Make sure the paths are correct. You shouldn't use relative paths like that because they depend on the location the calling function is. Try using WP constants, like 'ABSPATH' and functions like `site_url()`. That could be the problem, at least one of them. On the other hand, why do you deregister `jquery` scripts in general, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than de- and re-registering jQuery (which shouldn't be necessary if you're avoiding conflicts), try this:

```
function imagesloaded_script(){
      wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.imagesloaded.js', 'jquery');
      wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded');
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imagesloaded_script');
```

The function calls wp_register_script with three arguments: 1) a string to name the script, 2) the path of the script using `get_template_directory_uri()` to make sure you aren't messing up the paths, and 3) any dependancies - jQuery in this case.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still quite new to php. One of my questions was, how would I call various scripts using this method, because I also want to call: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script> as well as imagesloaded etc. So how would you could various jQuery scripts using this method, and (apologies if this is a dumb question) would you still have to include <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> in the header file above 'wp_head'?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call jQuery because when you call scripts that require it, you are listing it as a dependency.

Comment: To call other scripts, just add another function using the basic format of what I have in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've nearly got it working. Just a quick question, for every new function I add will I have to add it into the 'add_action' below like I've done with the previous actions?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use 'add_action' for all the scripts.